# Can google adsense ever generate pop-over adverts?

Tags: google-adsense

I've had adsense on a portion of my website pages for many years, in a 728x90 banner slot.  I've not changed any code relating to it recently.  Suddenly, as of a few days ago, I get occasional pop-overs.  I load up the site, with an advert on it, and when I click another link on the site the whole page blurs, like frosted glass, and in the middle is a portrait-oriented version of the advert that was showing on the page previously.

I HATE it.  And I feel it's against Google's best practices etc.  Does it mean my adsense code is getting hijacked somehow?

For now  I've commented the adsense code out, and my site now has no adverts and no pop-overs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Login your adsense account.
2. Click "Ads -> Overview" from left side menu list.
3. All your sites will be shown and select the edit icon from the website name list for remove popup ads.
4. Disable "Auto ads".

[image]

5. After disable auto ads, popup ads won't display in your webpage.

If you want to make more revenue from adsense, you should use auto and page level ads in your website.

Comment: Thanks.  It was an optimization that they'd run.  Revenue up SIGNIFICANTLY, but only from the square root of FA to FA.... and VERY alienating for my users, frankly I'd rather not have the adverts at all if that's what it takes!  What do you mean by "page level ads" though?

Comment: @Codemonkey page-level ads is a legacy name of auto-ads. They are the same product.  To expand on Dinesh'es answer - you probably shouldn't disable all auto ads. Auto ads includes few different formats. The one that you mention (fullscreen ad that shows when user clicks on a linnk) is the vignette ads. You might be ok with "in-page ads" or "anchor ads" as they provide more familiar ad experience. You can control which one to enable through "Ad formats" section.